# Pods.xcconfig could not find such file or directory in secure chatt

Tags: xmpp

I have downloaded code from Github when compile it gives errors.

PhaseScriptExecution Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/akhzarnazir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChatSecure-fjgwcobbgcchsxacwunevqxeteau/Build/Intermediates/ChatSecure.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChatSecure.build/Script-DCD88673560F4C18AC60C52B.sh
    cd "/Users/akhzarnazir/Desktop/WorkSpace/Third Parties ShouCangBao/ChatSecure-iOS-master"
    /bin/sh -c /Users/akhzarnazir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChatSecure-fjgwcobbgcchsxacwunevqxeteau/Build/Intermediates/ChatSecure.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChatSecure.build/Script-DCD88673560F4C18AC60C52B.sh

diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.